# HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, concordion

Here is my class which I'm trying to use:

```
data class GetAppResponse(
        val externalId: Long?,
        val lastUpdate: LocalDateTime?,
        var connectionInfo: ConnectionInfoDto? = null
) : BaseResponse()

data class ConnectionInfoDto(
        val catalogUrl: String?,
        val catalogPass: String?,
        val catalogLogin: String?
)
```

When I'm trying to serialize it to json:

```
fun partner() {
        partner.stubFor(get(anyUrl())
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withBody("{\"externalId\": 1, " +
                                "\"lastUpdate\": \"2020-01-01T10:00:00\", " +
                                "\"connectionInfo\": {" +
                                "\"catalogUrl\": " + archiveUrl + ", " +
                                "\"catalogPass\": \"user\", " +
                                "\"catalogLogin\": \"user\"}")
                ))
    }
```

I'm getting

```
 nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'http': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized token 'http': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
     at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 94] (through reference chain: GetAppResponse["connectionInfo"])
```

What is a reason and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
"\"catalogUrl\": " + archiveUrl + ", " +
```

with this:

```
"\"catalogUrl\": \"" + archiveUrl + "\", " +
```

Comment: archiveUrl variable is already String, does it matter?

Comment: I believe yes. Because in your concatenated String you will get: `"catalogUrl": http://something,` - which is not valid JSON

Answer (score 1):

For example you archiveUrl value is asdsad so your full string body will be

```
{"externalId": 1, "lastUpdate": "2020-01-01T10:00:00", "connectionInfo": {"catalogUrl": asdsad, "catalogPass": "user", "catalogLogin": "user"}
```

and you can see that the catalogUrl value is not a string so giving the error.

So if you want to successfully parse the string to your object just change the catalogUrl value to represent in double quotes.

your string body

```
"{\"externalId\": 1, " +
                "\"lastUpdate\": \"2020-01-01T10:00:00\", " +
                "\"connectionInfo\": {" +
                "\"catalogUrl\": \"" + archiveUrl + "\", " +
                "\"catalogPass\": \"user\", " +
                "\"catalogLogin\": \"user\"}"
```

and json response:-

```
{"externalId": 1, "lastUpdate": "2020-01-01T10:00:00", "connectionInfo": {"catalogUrl": "asdsad", "catalogPass": "user", "catalogLogin": "user"}
```